# Bot Framework [Direct Line]: Saving and retrieving userData based on custom ID

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I'm using Bot Framework's Direct Line channel to integrate my bot to a custom front end.

The bot asks the user questions similar to a web form. Ex: Name, phone, email etc.

A major use case that I want to accomplish with this is to be able to save a user's "userData" (and possibly "conversationData") based on one of these custom fields, say, the phone number. Hence, it should be then also be possible to retrieve the userData in the future just using the phone numbers as well.

An example flow could work like:

- Ask for name
- Ask for email
- Ask for Phone, then create the userData doc on, say, an Azure CosmosDB instance.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to accomplish this on a directline setting, where you don't have the inbuilt channel-userID identifiers (found in Facebook, Skype etc), that make the data-bag storage and retrieval work.

Comment: You have a channel ID and user ID even on Direct Line channel. So you could just override the user ID with the Key you want, and then use the BotState to store the items

Comment: Your directline client will need to create a userid when messaging the bot.  And, UserData will already have been created by the time the questions are answered.  So, you can just add a table for mapping this UserId to the supplied phone number.  Then, if you want to query userdata based on phone number, first look up the phone number in your mapping table and use the UserId to retrieve UserData from CosmosDb

Comment: "Then, if you want to query userdata based on phone number, first look up the phone number in your mapping table and use the UserId to retrieve UserData from CosmosDb"

Ok, I can envision how the retrieval would of UserID based on the phone number would work, but how do we retrieve the resulting userData and use it in the context of an ongoing conversation ?

Comment: We have some documentation on how to manipulate state data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage  and our blog also discusses this: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/04/02/reminder-the-bot-framework-state-service-has-been-retired-what-you-need-to-know/ https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/26/saving-state-sql-dotnet/ https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/21/saving-state-azure-nodejs/  https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/18/saving-state-azure-extensions/